# Files unavailable although drive is mounted on boot

Tags: boot, mount, lubuntu

I'm new to Ubuntu. I have installed Lubuntu on USB drive. When my movie player tries to access my movie folders, which are in my internal hard drive, they are unavailable. If I go to File Manager and access them manually, everything is fine, and then the movie player can access them too.

I think my problem is that my internal hard drive, although it is auto-mounted on boot, is not listed when I use the `df` command. After I access the drive using File Manager I can then see it in the `df` list.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the contents of your `/etc/fstab` file - it sounds to me like the internal drive is **not** mounted at boot

Comment: Instead of adding the solution to your question, please post it as an answer :) [here is a draft you can copy and paste into the answer box](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23851211/) with fixed formatting. You should [edit] your question with the contents of `/etc/fstab` too - you can permanently solve the issue by adding a line there for the partition

Answer (score 1):

OP's own answer edited out of the question:

> Solved. The problem was that the drive was ready to mount and not
>   actually mounted. So I wrote this on startup:
>
> ```
> sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sbb3 /media/MyStorage
> ```
>
> where `/dev/sbb3` is the partition to mount and `/media/Mystorage` is
>   the place to mount it.